Dash Input not callingback after Google Places Autocompletion
I have the following callback
@app.callback(Output("full_address", "data"),
        Input("corrected_address", "value"))
        def store_address(inputdata):
            print(inputdata)
            return inputdata

which is tied to the element created by
dbc.Input(id="corrected_address")

This element uses a Google Places auto complete element:
var input = document.getElementById('corrected_address');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry', 'name']);

The auto complete shows up as expected.

However, when completed, the callback is not triggered

Updating the field by adding or removing a character updates the value as expected.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. How can I get the callback to trigger?
I'm using dash and dash-bootstrap-components, Python 3.10.12.

One idea would be to listen for the autocomplete "place_changed" event directly (on the client side) and do the logic in the js handler rather than in a backend callback (cf. doc). Then from there, in the js handler, you can still manually trigger a change event or something like that so that the backend callback can also run when user selects a place.

@EricLavault It would appear that Dash is ignoring dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));. I attempted to trigger the server side callback with it within the place_changed callback and nothing happens. Further research lead me to discover that Dash has some weird back end stuff with how it handles events, and manually triggered events get ignored more often than now. I could be wrong and just doing it wrong.

I've found a solution that works quite nicely in my opinion. Due to Dash ignoring changes to values from JavaScript, going as far as to ignore manually issued change events, dash_extensions EventListener can be used alongside a custom event and a serverside callback to update the fields value appropriately on the backend.
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, clientside_callback
from dash_extensions import EventListener
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ALL
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


GAPI_STRING = ""

external_scripts = [
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+GAPI_STRING+'&libraries=places',
]
app = Dash(
    __name__,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    external_scripts=external_scripts,
)


# The event used to pass the value of the autocomplete field from the client to the server
manual_notify = {"event": "autocomplete_finished", "props": ["srcElement.value"]}

app.layout = [
    html.Div([html.Label("Current Address:", id="address_label")], id="display_div"),
    html.Div([
        EventListener(
            [
                dbc.Input(id="auto_complete_field")
            ], events=[manual_notify], logging=True, id="event_listener"
        ),
    ], id="auto_complete_div")
]

clientside_callback(
    """
    // Used to initiate autocomplete after the Dash form is created
    // This function requires the element to be present,
    // and if it were in a normal external script, it would not run
    // and auto complete would not initialize.
    
    // This callback essentially takes in the element when it's created
    // Runs the autocomplete setup functions, and returns the element as
    // it is.
    function(facade1) {
        // setup autcomplete
        var input = document.getElementById('auto_complete_field');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry', 'name']);
        
        // dispatch the "autocomplete_finished" event when "place_changed" is dispatched.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => input.dispatchEvent(new Event("autocomplete_finished")));
        return facade1;
    }
    """,
    Output("auto_complete_div", "children"),
    Input("auto_complete_div", "children")
)

# When the autocomplete_finished event is dispatched
# this callback will handle it, and outputs the full
# address to the autocomplete fields value property,
# syncing the backend value with the front end value
@app.callback(
    Output("auto_complete_field", "value"),
    Input("event_listener", "n_events"),
    State("event_listener", "event"))
def store_address(n_events, event):
    if event is None:
        raise PreventUpdate()
    return event["srcElement.value"]

# This updates the current address label using the
# autocomplete fields value property as the input,
# proving that the internal value is the same as
# the one in the clients input field.
@app.callback(Output("address_label", "children"), Input("auto_complete_field", "value"))
def print_address(field_value):
    if field_value == None:
        raise PreventUpdate()
    return "Current Address: " + field_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

I hope this helps somebody! This was a doozy to figure out.
